# Is it possible to convert the battery power supply in old devices?

Tags: power, batteries, keyboard

I have an old Yamaha keyboard/synthesizer lying around that I'd like to start using with battery power. However, it takes 6xC (1.5v) batteries to power the thing up. My question is, is it possible to do some tinkering around and get this keyboard to support a more modern power supply?

My ideal (probably naive) solution would be a laptop-style battery pack that I can charge via mains without needing to remove the battery and put it in a wall charger. But mainly, I don't want to have to keep buying 6 C batteries (old, expensive, inefficient) to power the keyboard.

If this is possible, how is it done? If it's not, are there any other solutions that are similar?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Shopping questions are generally closed down fairly quickly on this site. Please edit your post and try to make it more of a design question. Do a bit of research on rechargeable batteries and chargers and post the info with a specific, answerable question.

Comment: 6*1.5V = 9V. If you are going to use a laptop battery, get yourself a buck converter to step down the 19V or whatever to 9V. Also, does the keyboard have an auxiliary power jack?

Comment: Replacing it is easy. Regulate the new battery pack output voltage to the old battery pack's expected voltage. That's pretty much it.

Comment: Often, things like an old synth have a socket for an external mains-powered low-voltage supply.  If you don't need a portable battery supply, and are okay using it with a mains electricity supply, just buy a 9V 'wall-wart' power adapter, and make a way to connect that to your synth. If you take the cover of the synth, it is likely feasible to see how to make the connections even if there is no ready-made socket.

Comment: Thanks, the keyboard does have an auxilliary power jack, but I specifically want to make it portable. My main concern is the size/shape of the battery pack. Let's say I bought an Li-Ion battery pack. Given that the battery compartment for the keyboard expects 6xC batteries in series, with one end of the power terminal situated quite far down inside the compartment, how would I even wire the new battery up? Is it just a case of soldering the wires to each terminal?

Comment: Do some research, find a DC to DC converter. Draw a diagram with the circuit tool of what you think is appropriate with the circuit tool

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to obtain NiMh rechargeables of the same size, C in this case. Then you get a NiMh recharger and wire in your own plug/jack to connect the charger. There you have it.